# Custom project of Geoexplorer

Tags: geoexplorer

Is there some custom project existing of geoexplorer free downloadable? I'm student and I'm doing a stage. I need to have a query mask for my map but I'm not able to do it with sdk-suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you build the [old version](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/GeoExplorer) (before it was integrated in the suite repo). It should have query support and filtering.